# How do I configure an AWS Glue Crawler for GPX XML FIles?

Tags: xml, gpx, aws-glue

I have thousands of files stored in an S3 bucket. They are all text files, XML, in GPX (version 1.0) schema.

When I create a Crawler for this S3 bucket using AWS Glue's XML classifier, the Crawler returns 0 records from these data.

Do I need to specify the XML schema in the crawler somehow? Do I need to specify a customer classifier? Does the schema definition need to appear within each GPX file?